# Is a number irrational if and only if for some $k > 1$ its $k$-base representation is infinite and non-periodic?

Tags: arithmetic, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I already know that a real number is irrational if and only if its decimal representation is infinite and non-periodic. Is this result valid for any base $k > 1$?

Comment: Yes, and the proof is the same.

Comment: If its representation is infinite but periodic that might mean the number is rational after all, though coprime to the base. For example, compare the decimal representation of $\frac{1}{7}$ to its binary representation.